# openssl AES GCM Implementation

Tags: openssl

I was going through openssl 1.0.1h code in order to see how AES-GCM is implemented. I came across the AES modes source file like aes_cbc, aes_ecb etc but I am unable to find AES-GCM source files. Is it implemented differently as compared to other modes? Can anyone recommend some Document that shows the complete Implementation flow of GCM-AES-256 in openssl 1.0.1h upto level of lookup tables and low level implementation?

Comment: First, `cd <openssl src>`. Then `grep -R -i GCM *`. You get lots of hits to look at. You probably want to look at `crypto/modes/gcm128.c` and `crypto/evp/e_aes.c` around the use of `EVP_AES_GCM_CTX`. There's also a fair bit of assembly language, for example, in `crypto/modes/asm/ghash-armv4.pl`. You can see it used in the SSL portion of the library in `ssl/s3_lib.c` and `ssl/t1_enc.c`.

Comment: Sorry there is a typo...i missed adding AES-GCM-256...yes I have found 128 version before but cannot locate 256. Now looking in detail all files you have mentioned..